# Confusion over referencing class objects (child classes) and accessing methods

Tags: java, reference, parent-child, accessor

Is it okay to reference (if that's even what it's doing) a class object like: private SomeClass someclass; As in below? It works fine, but does it break encapsulation? Book is child of Reading and Reading is child of content.

Also, is doing this okay? ((Game) c.getValue()).returnNameAndOs()); The OS class object is inside the Game class object.

I'm just concerned with doing things correctly, or doing it better.

```
public abstract class Content {

  Private List<Comment> Review = new ArrayList<Comment>();

  private Reading reading; // is this bad practice
  private Book book; 

  private String ID;
  private String Application_Name;

  private int No_of_Downloads = 0;
  private double Price = 0;

  // overridden
  public Content(String iD, String application_Name, double price) {
    super();
    ID = iD;
    Application_Name = application_Name;
    Price = price;
  }

// overridden 
  public Content(String iD, String application_Name) {
    super();
    ID = iD;
    Application_Name = application_Name;
  }

  public void addReviews(Comment a) {

    this.Review.add(a);
    System.out.println(a.getusrname()+" added review on 
    "+this.getApplication_Name()+": "+a.getUsrComment());
  }
// etc...
}
```

Comment: Aggregation and Composition are the forms of association. In your case, you are taking reference of another  class which is composition. Encapsulation says that you should keep the field and related methods in the same class. But you can call those methods in other class.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an abstract class, you cannot initialise it , hence no use of constructor,

I believe list of comments “review” is associated with the content. It should be private and have getter setter like other variables

Comment: It is an abstract class. I just updated my code. There are two constructors in Content that are overridden in various child classes (with added instance variables) . It was those added instant variables I was having trouble with. There is a class called Comments (which are replies to 'reviews') with an ArrayList that references itself <Comments>. The Reviews/Comments side of thing works fine.